# How to write a numpy array to a byte memorystream?

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, tdd, binary-data

I'm unit testing code in Python2.7 that writes numpy array via [`ndarray.tofile(fileHandle,..)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html). Since doing file IO in unit tests is bad for a number of reasons, how do I substitute a byte memorystream in place of the file handle? (`io.BytesIO` failed to work because `ndarray.toFile()` asks it for a file name.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't `tobytes` [[1]](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html#numpy.ndarray.tobytes) and `frombuffer` [[2]](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html#numpy.frombuffer) do what you need for testing purposes?

```
m = np.random.rand(5,3)
b = m.tobytes()
mb = np.frombuffer(b).reshape(m.shape)
```

Comment: That will work assuming that tofile() doesn't deviate from tobytes. This is the best answer for the current state of numpy. It's unfortunate that tofile doesn't accept a stream so it would be possible to directly test unit test tofile() API.

Answer (score 0):

Would a [`tempfile.TemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html?highlight=tempfile#tempfile.TemporaryFile) suit your purposes?

It exposes the same interface as a normal file object, so you can pass it directly to `np.ndarray.tofile()`, and it will be deleted immediately when it is either explicitly closed or garbage collected:

```
import numpy as np
from tempfile import TemporaryFile

x = np.random.randn(1000)

with TemporaryFile() as t:
    x.tofile(t)
    # do your testing...

# t is closed and deleted
```

It will, however, reside temporarily on disk (usually in `/tmp/` on a Linux machine), but I don't see an easy way to avoid I/O altogether, since `.tofile()` will ultimately need a valid OS-level file descriptor.

Comment: Building automated unit tests with file io leaves race conditions that cause tests to not behave deterministically.  If one adds sleeps to ensure asynchronous file io is finished, then you have slow unit tests and slow unit tests aren't scalable to having hundreds of unit tests which run in a few seconds.  What you suggest is perfectly fine for a few system tests but that's not what I'm doing.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a bit more information about your requirements. How much data are you writing? Do you need to be able to read it back? What sort of race conditions are you concerned about? Do you absolutely need to use `tofile`?

Comment: I want to test an application that uses numbpy. The application is creating files. I need to write out a bytes to kb to confirm if the correct bytes are being produced. To write automated tests that will work consistently across hardware, I want to check the in memory output stream before it is written to a file.  This last part I'm finding difficult because although the api docs for nddarray.toFile() say it takes a filehandler argument or a handle to a stream, it doesn't handle the bytesIo handle I'm passing in.  I fear that as of now, it requires a file handler. :-)

Comment: I'm looking at nddarray.toBytes() and doing some tests to see if I can assume toBytes() will mirror what is written out with toFile().  If that works, I'll figure something out.  Maybe use it for mocking.

Comment: FWIW, here's the [relevant method](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/d033b6e19fc95a1f1fd6592de8318178368011b1/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c#L552-L585) in the C source, which in turn calls [`npy_PyFile_Dup2`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e3b2bc0b0f31482cd112660393245116ae55ecbf/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_3kcompat.h#L148-L219) (note the use of `os.dup` to duplicate a file descriptor). This is all going on at C level, so I don't see an easy way to fake an open file via a Python object.

Comment: If you're running Linux and you don't need the solution to be platform-independent then I suppose you could do something like creating a normal Python file inside a `tmpfs`